# сравнение значений int и str

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, у меня есть функция поиска по ключу в стеке (выводит индекс элемента)

```
def find(self, key):
        temp = self.head
        i = 1
        while temp is not None:
            if key == temp.element:
                return i
            temp = temp.next_node
            i += 1
        return -1
```

затем выполняю заполнение стека и ввожу значение, индекс которого нужно найти

```
stack.push(2)
stack.push("a")
stack.push(3)
stack.push(4)
stack.push("b")

print(stack.find(input()))
```

если я ввожу в input() число,например, 3, то возвращает значение -1, то есть как будто такого числа в стеке нет. я понимаю, что это происходит, так как в input() - строковое значение и можно сделать int(input()). но я хочу сделать стек универсальным, чтобы работало и для str и для int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приводите оба сравниваемых значения к строкам, и тогда уже сравнивайте, тогда будет находить и числа и строки:

```
if str(key) == str(temp.element):
    return i
```

Это в случае, если вы хотите сохранить тип помещаемых в стек элементов. Если сохранение типа не нужно, то помещайте элементы сразу приведя к строке и ищите тоже приведя искомое к строке.